# how check what datagridview checkbox has been selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have toughly searched and not able to find how to check what datagridview checkbox has been selected

I am using C# code and i was wondering how would i be able to check what check boxes have been selected and hold the row index so that i can look at the data grid-view information

i already have already added the checkbox's

this is my code so far "

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
            chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
            chk.Name = "chk";
```

"

Comment: Do you have multiple checkboxes within one datagridview row? Do you use databinding?

Comment: "I am using c# code" what c# code? How are you binding? What is the DataGridView column name with a checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {


            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox2");
            if (Ckbox.Checked)
            {
               //........

            }
        }
```

Comment: you can add this code to Click Event of Button.this code check for every checkboxs in each row if have been checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if(cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        {
            isChecked = (datagridview.GetChildByPoint(new Point(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex)) as CheckBox).Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

This might solve your issue. If you have set the TrueValue and FalseValue of the column, then you could more easily just check the current value against these values and deduce its checked state.

Comment: how wouldi go about stteing the true and flase value of the cioloumn and also will this return me a number

Comment: no it will return you a bool for whether the underlying control is checked

Comment: if its a read/write column,  then you can use the above to set the value also, but for setting, its alot less cumbersome if you just check column index and set  value to "true" or "false"

Comment: all i would like to know based on the code i have put in above what row it refers to when checked.

Comment: Oh well in that case, you might want to handle the EditingControlShowing event of the DataGridView, that will trigger anytime a cell is being edited, and you can then attach the checkbox control to a Checked handler, and handle that event